# Redirect one UDP port to another on local network

Tags: networking, proxy, port-forwarding, port

I’ve got two Minecraft servers running in a Docker. Each server runs on a different port: Bedrock_Server_1 on default port 19132 and the Bedrock_Server_2 on non-standard port 19140.

I can access them from most devices, but not from my PS4. PS4 doesn’t support servers yet. But it does support “Friends” and I can connect to one of my servers, the one that uses the default port 19132.

I wonder if that would be possible to make the Server_2 appear as a separate device (with e. g. different IP) that also uses the default port 19132?

I was trying to redirect the port with the Proxy running on the Raspi but got stuck.
Also saw something about socat that might be useful for that purpose...

Sorry if it is a noob question...

I have attached schematics:

[image]

Comment: It’s your local network. Use different IP addresses for your servers, the end. // Port forwarding on the router only works so seamlessly because return traffic also passes through it.

Comment: @DanielB servers run in the Docker so they don’t have IP addresses per se...

Comment: Docker networking is configurable. MACVLAN networks can bring your containers to the real network directly.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @DanielB but I don’t seem to get those containers working with MACVLAN at all. Only with the default network (which is BRIDGE I believe) and `ports` configured on each container separately in `docker-compose`. I also read that it is not possible to assign separate IPs for each container on macos, not sure if that’s related.